# Why is `this.setState` not working just in IE?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, gatsby

I am managing sidebar visibility and React-Table loading state with `this.state` like following.
(I am building web site with React.js, Gatsby and semantic-ui-react. )

```
class SidebarRightOverlay extends Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state = {
         visible: false,
         loading: true
     }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     this.setState({loading: false})
  }

  render() {
    const toggleVisibility = () => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })
    const { visible } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleVisibility}>Toggle Visibility</Button>
            .
            .
            .
            .
```

This way should be usual and not erroneous, because the sidebar appears after clicking button and loading display on table disappears after loaded table data **in Chrome and Firefox.**

However, they doesn't work **in IE11, Edge and wine-IE.**
I think that `this.setState` is not working just in IE11, Edge and wine-IE.
Please tell me how to let them work.

Incidentally, I tested my web site built by `gatsby build` and deployed by `firebase deploy` .

**Add:**
Sorry. This code is made by copy and paste for posting here. I made a mistake. There is no this in the actual code. Please suppose there is no error in Gatsby build process.

Comment: `this.toggleVisibility` ? it looks like a local var only. no need for `this.`

Comment: @DimitarChristoff you are very correct, which incidentally would make this code fail in all browsers and not just those produced by Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry. This code is made by copy and paste for posting here. I made a mistake. There is no `this` in the actual code. Please suppose there is no error in Gatsby build process.

Comment: What is `Button`? I don't see it imported. Do you mean `button`? This is not a problem with `setState`. What console errors do you see?

Comment: Button of Semantic UI React. I did not see console error. This problem may be concerned about webpack or babel config.

Comment: You should never setState in the render method, which your function is bound to. This will cause **INFINITE** rendering. Move it to a class function and all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correcte because you put a `this.setState` in `render()` method, that's not correcte because, when the state is update via `this.setState({...})`, the `render()` method is call again